# where to write a log file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog, special-folders, network-service

I'm using nlog to write log files for debugging purposes. Currently the log file location is set to:

```
<target 
    name="file" 
    xsi:type="File" 
    fileName="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/x/y.log"
```

but this is resulting in a the file being written to `c:\x\y.log`, not `%windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\x\y.log`, as I would expect with asp.net/IIS running under `NETWORK SERVICE` account.

Checking the value for `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` from the web application yields an empty/null string, which at least explains why my logs are ending up in the root.

So really two questions:

We have services written and running under `NETWORK SERVICE` account that resolve this path correctly. What's special about asp.net/IIS such that no value is returned for this special folder?

Where is a safe and sensible place to write a log to, given that my asp.net process is running under `NETWORK SERVICE` account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my knowledge is correct, the problem is that IIS doesn't load the profile for the user Network Service.

You could adjust this setting in the properties of the application pool ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity.aspx))

[image: load the user profile of the application pool identity]

If you set this parameter to `true`, the call to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` should return a correct result.

See also:

- [Wrong path returned by Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationFolder) under IIS6 WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943626/wrong-path-returned-by-environment-getfolderpathenvironment-specialfolder-applic)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/890fa85a-b11a-4fbe-a333-cbe69abd72a7/
- [You can now load the user profile of the application pool identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity.aspx)

If it does not work, I would recommend to create a folder with the appropriate rights for the service account for logging purposes.

Comment: Perfect. I ended up going for your last option but it's good to know where I was going wrong.