# Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData returns the wrong folder

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a strange problem: my .NET 4.0 WPF application is saving data to the ApplicationData folder.

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\myProgram\\";
```

99.9% of the cases are working great, but on some computers it returns the wrong folder - instead of returning the user folder it returns another folder:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\myProgram\  --correct
C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\myProgram\       --wrong
```

The wrong folder has no write/read permission so my program doesn't work.

It seems the program is running under a different user, but if I check the Task Manager the user is the logged one.

The problem seems to be occurring with domain users with few permissions.

Comment: Is you app a Web App?

Comment: No, it's a wpf app, framework 4.0

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but **use Path.Combine!**

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3953509/33690

Comment: @Xaisoft It's not a web service...

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - Sorry, just realized that.

Comment: @bastianonm It's not, it's just that it's better. Won't fix the problem at hand, and the problem has something to do with Shell32...

Comment: it's not a common problem but it's happening more and more frequently.. I've double check everything but I'm sure I forgot something!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `LocalApplicationData` instead in the first place? I mean, what's the purpose to roam the data, if the application is only installed on one machine?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici yes, now I'm testing CommonApplicationData folder. In this way all user share the same files

Comment: Sorry, no solution! I moved to 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)

Comment: One my my client have same problem on Vista SP2 and I came here due to the same reason...

Answer (score 18):

Do you *also* create a text file to write?

If so save a file such as:

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

var filePath = Path.Combine(path, "filetowrite.log"); // Handles whether there is a `\` or not.

if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
     ......................
}
```

**Note** also before doing any file operations, one should check if directory exists.

Comment: Always use Path.Combine, never "+" as you do not know if the path ends with a backslahs (or uses backslashes at all).