# How to create file text in "AppData\Roaming" for any user in C#

Tags: c#

I'd like save date my app but I'm not knowing if app save for different users, Example if "andy" I can't use ("C:\Users\Game maker\AppData\Roaming") ,So How to create file in "AppData\Roaming\MaxrayStudyApp" for any user .

```
    Computer myComputer = new Computer();
        myComputer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Game maker\AppData\Roaming\MaxrayStudy\data.txt","", false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the path of the current user's "Application Data" folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915210/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-users-application-data-folder)

Comment: Look up https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+environment.specialfolder and if you get stuck, post the code you've tried and the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 5):

Almost a duplicate of this one: [Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData returns the wrong folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484177/2524589)

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

That should get the folder you need then use Path.Combine() to write to a directory in that folder.

```
var roamingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filePath = Path.Combine(roamingDirectory, "MaxrayStudy\\data.txt");
```

Comment: thanks for answer me I write the 3 lines but I didn't find "data.txt" file :(

Comment: Might not have permissions. Hard to say. Can you create a file there manually and write to it with notepad or something?

Comment: yes I can and I run my app As adminaster but it isn't working

Comment: Is it throwing an error? You have to make sure the directory exists. Check out the CreateDirectory() method then try to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

I restart my windows and I write this

```
string filePath =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

        filePath= (filePath+@"\MaxrayStudyApp\data.txt");
        string path =Convert.ToString(filePath);
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
    new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath,false)){
            file.WriteLine(" XP : 0");}
```